# How to prune partitions with joins in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables with two different type of events, both tables are partitioned by the event's timestamp and I would like to create a view of the join between them with the events with the same id and in the same quarter.

```
CREATE TABLE `proj1.test.table1` ( event_timestamp TIMESTAMP, id INT64 )
PARTITION BY DATE(event_timestamp);

CREATE TABLE `proj1.test.table2` ( event_timestamp TIMESTAMP, id INT64 )
PARTITION BY DATE(event_timestamp);

CREATE VIEW `proj1.test.view1` AS
  SELECT t1.event_timestamp,t1.id
  FROM `proj1.test.table1` t1
  INNER JOIN `proj1.test.table2` t2
  USING (id)
  WHERE TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(t1.event_timestamp, quarter) = TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(t2.event_timestamp, quarter)
;
```

The problem is that this view only is pruning the partitions in the first table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test.view1
WHERE event_timestamp BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-01'
```

To be able to prune the partitions of both tables I have to use a literal expression instead of a computed value:

```
CREATE VIEW `proj1.test.view1` AS
  SELECT t1.event_timestamp,t1.id
  FROM `proj1.test.table1` t1
  INNER JOIN `proj1.test.table2` t2
  USING (id)
  WHERE TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(t2.event_timestamp, quarter) = '2020-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have described [the intended behaviour](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#isolate_the_partition_column_in_your_filter). I would try either:

1. Get rid of the view and double up the filter in the `WHERE` clause.  I do this often as it is easy:

```
    SELECT t1.event_timestamp,t1.id
    FROM test.table1 t1
    INNER JOIN test.table2 t2
    USING (id)
    WHERE t1.event_timestamp BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-01'
    AND t2.event_timestamp BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-01'
```

2. If the query is always going to be based on the quarter, add another column and partition and join on it:

```
CREATE TABLE test.table1 ( event_timestamp TIMESTAMP, event_quarter DATE, id INT64 )
PARTITION BY event_quarter;

CREATE TABLE test.table2 ( event_timestamp TIMESTAMP, event_quarter DATE, id INT64 )
PARTITION BY event_quarter;

CREATE VIEW test.view1 AS
  SELECT t1.*
  FROM test.table1 t1
  INNER JOIN test.table2 t2
  USING (id, event_quarter);

SELECT * 
FROM test.view1
WHERE event_quarter = '2020-01-01'
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, both options are valid although I would like to have a cleaner one. The first option with real cases (more than two tables) if very complicated to handle it. The second option, from my point the view, is better but you have to duplicate  a column (with their typical problems) and lost the option to use smaller partitions (e.g by day) using the timestamp.